# How to pass contentType information from Burzum/FileStorage to KnpLabs/Gaufrette

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-s3, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.4 application using the [Burzum/FileStorage](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage) plugin (which uses [KnpLabs/Gaufrette](https://github.com/knplabs/Gaufrette)) to manage uploads to AWS S3. Unfortunately, I was running into the issue of MS Office files (docx, xlsx, etc) being detected as ZIP files.

I altered my code to use finfo first and if it detects zip, look at the extension to see if it maybe is an office file. Now I can pass this correct mimetype on to the file_storage table by doing a patchEntity. So far so good.

However, the FileStorage plugin calls KnpLabs/Gaufrette to actually send the file to S3, but it doesn't seem to send along the mimetype/contenttype. So Gaufrette then does its own little finfo trick in the [AwsS3 Adapter](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/AwsS3.php#L166), writing a metadata field 'Content-Type: application/zip' to the item on S3, causing the Office file to be downloaded as a zip file...

Is there any way to set the correct content type in the options of the AwsS3 adapter?

thanks!

Comment: I was about to add a new comment, as the storage seems to be a `\Gaufrette\Filesystem` instance. If the storage is provided with the event, then you should be able to use that one in a listener, like `$storage->getAdapter()->setMetadata('filename', ['ContentType' => 'custom-content-type'])` (if the adapter implements `\Gaufrette\Adapter\MetadataSupporter`). But again, I'm not familiar with the plugin.

Comment: The Burzum FileStorageTable dispatches an event on save, that is picked up by the AbstractListener in the same plugin, which in turn creates the Gaufrette StorageAdapter. All of this happens in the plugins and I don't see how I can influence this process without editing the plugins. Or do you mean I can listen for this event as well, somehow get a hold of the storageAdapter and do a setMetadata from outside the plugin?

Comment: That would be one way, but looking at [**the docs**](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/1.2.1/docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md) it seems that you have to register a listener in the first place for anything to happen at all?, so you should also be able to create an extended listener class that overrides for example `AbstractListener::_storeFile()` and modifies the storage adapters metadata.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!

Comment: The whole storage stuff is mostly event driven. Is this the same problem you have? https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/issues/36 I remember that I had to provide 1 or 2 PRs to Gaufrette for some problems as well. Let me know if there are more issues but I'll be out over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! If you wanna post it as an answer here I'll upvote. Else, I'll post it myself and give a shoutout to you. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was mentioned here: https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/issues/36

It is possible accessing the adapter and setting, for instance, the Content Type using the following code:

```
$Adapter = \Burzum\FileStorage\Storage\StorageManager::adapter('S3');
$Adapter->getAdapter()->setMetadata($key, array('contentType' => 'whatever'));
```

Thanks to burzum for pointing this out!